# How can I access the bytes form an integer

Tags: c

I am trying to do **xor** between the bytes(or octets) of a pixel from a `.bmp` file and 3 of the bytes from a randomly generated integer *excluding the most significant one*. I kind of understand that the most significant byte is depending on endianness and generally it is the first one transmitted in a sentence. 
In the `pix` array, I have stored every octet of every pixel. 
`w` and `h` are both equal to `800` and are the dimensions of the `.bmp` picture(800 x 800) and `R` is an array of random numbers.

I tried to do the following operations but it would give me a *segmentation fault* after some incrementations.

```
unsigned char *pix = malloc((3 * w * h) * sizeof(unsigned char));

for(int i = 0; i < (3 * w * h); i++)
    fread(&pix[i], sizeof(char), 1, fin);

uint32_t *R = malloc((3 * ((2 * w * h) - 1)) * sizeof(uint32_t));
unsigned char bytes[4];

for(k = 0; k < (3 * w * h); k = k + 3)
{
    bytes[0] = (R[3 * w * h + k] >> 24) & 0xFF;
    bytes[1] = (R[3 * w * h + k] >> 16) & 0xFF;
    bytes[2] = (R[3 * w * h + k] >> 8)  & 0xFF;
    bytes[3] =  R[3 * w * h + k]        & 0xFF;

    ch[k]     = bytes[1] ^ pix[k];
    ch[k + 1] = bytes[2] ^ pix[k + 1];
    ch[k + 2] = bytes[3] ^ pix[k + 2]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `R` and`pix`?

Comment: Will `3*w*h+k` always be a valid index of `R`? Will `k`, `k + 1` and `k + 2` always be valid indexes of `ch` and `pix`?

Comment: And have you tried [debugging your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i edited the post to include the declarations

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i will read the link that you gave me and come back with an answer

Comment: by definition `sizeof(char)` is 1

Comment: In what you show, `R` is not initialized. That is not on all systems/compilers the same as "random numbers". The system may have initialized it with trap values.

Comment: You must also check the return value of malloc to be sure the requested amount of memory was allocated.

Comment: remains the definition of `ch`. The rest of the code seems OK.

Comment: It might not immediately solve your problem, but better variable names would certainly help both people helping you and yourself - e.g. `const int pix_size = 3 * w * h;`

Comment: The indexing into `R` looks weird - should that not just be `R[k]`? Seems like things would be simplified if the number of elements in `R` and `pix` was the same?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: `uint32_t` cannot have trap representations because it has only value bits (no padding bits), and each combination of value bit values is required to represent a value.

Comment: You should edit your question to show a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Showing just a fragment of code omits things outside the code that may cause the problem and it interferes with people compiling and executing the code so that they can debug it. Additionally, reducing a program to a minimal example often reveals the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef enum
{
    LITTLE = 0xff000000,
    BIG = 0x000000ff,
}ENDIANESS;

static ENDIANESS endianess;

ENDIANESS DetectEndianess(void)
{
    union
    {
        uint8_t u8[sizeof(unsigned int)];
        unsigned int u;
    }udata = {.u = 0xff};

    return (endianess = (udata.u8[0] == 0xff ? LITTLE : BIG));
}

static inline ENDIANESS GetEndianess(void)
{
    return endianess;
}

uint32_t GetUint32FromRGB(uint8_t *ptr)
{
    union u32u
    {
        uint8_t u8[4];
        uint32_t u32;
    }union32 = (GetEndianess() == LITTLE ? (union u32u){.u8[0] = *ptr, .u8[1] = *(ptr + 1), .u8[2] = *(ptr + 2)} : (union u32u){.u8[2] = *ptr, .u8[1] = *(ptr + 1), .u8[0] = *(ptr + 2)});

    return union32.u32 & GetEndianess();
}

uint32_t Xor3LowerBytes(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return (a & GetEndianess()) ^ (b & GetEndianess());
}
```

---

Or if you do not care abut endianess (in this example LITTLE)

```
uint32_t Xor3lowerBytes(void *ptr, uint32_t value)
{
    uint32_t *u32 = ptr;

    return (*u32 & 0xff000000) ^ value;
}
```

Comment: (1) This answer does not address the segmentation fault reported in the question and does not address issues with the code in the question. (2) Bare code without documentation (either in comments or in text outside the code) does not answer the question. (3) ANDing with `0xff` or `0xff000000` isolates one byte but three are desired. (4) It appears all `GetEndianess` does is return a `uint32_t` with 0xff in its high-addressed byte, in which case it and all its supporting routines and definitions can be replaced with `(union { uint8_t a[4]; uint32_t b; }) { .a[3] = 0xff; } .b`.

Comment: (5) Enumerator values are restricted to the range of `int`, so `LITTLE = 0xff000000` is not portable. (6) `GetUINT32FromRGB` always returns 0, due to the aforementioned one-byte-instead-of-three problem.